# window.open not loading tab properly

Tags: javascript, html, tfs, window.open

I'm trying to make a feature where clicking on a button will load a window in a new tab. 
For some reason, this is not working.

In my HTML, I have

```
<button onClick="myFunction"> Try it </button>
```

and the corresponding function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        window.open("http://localhost:9000/", "_blank");
    }
</script>
```

For some more details, this is being done from a widget on Team Foundation Server and I'm trying to load a SonarQube page.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzLAT.png) is what the page should look like, 
but when I try to access it with the above code it just loads a blank page. However, the proper favicon is there.
If I load my HTML page normally (not on Team Foundation Server), clicking the button loads the page properly, so I think it has something to do with Team Foundation Server, but I have no clue what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: well the image shows /products but the link you are loading does not have that.... Is there a redirect?

Comment: @epascarello Yeah that's a redirect. Going to http://localhost:9000/ will automatically redirect to http://localhost:9000/projects. If I change my javascript to include the products at the end of the URL the result is the same :/

Comment: `<button type="button" onClick="myFunction"` You should add type to the button so it does not act like a submit button. Doubt that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below snippet in your HTML.

```
<a href="http://localhost:9000/" target="_blank">
<button>Button Name</button>
</a>
```

Or Java Script:

```
<input type="button" value="button name" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:9000/')" />
```

Worked for me and it will open an actual new 'popup' window rather than a new full browser or tab.

Comment: @kicksticks Have you tried the snippet, is that work for you?

Comment: sorry I didn't see this. No it didn't